# OpenSSH anything like 'internal-sftp' but for SCP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp, chroot, jail

I'm running Debian stable and I'm looking to establish the following environment for users in my 'sftponly' group:

- jailed
- can transfer with SFTP
- can transfer with SCP
- cannot login interactively with SSH

From my experimentation and research, it seems that the following stanza in sshd_config gets me 90% there:

```
Match group sftponly
ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

This gives me jailed SFTP and no SSH, which is good. But it also disables SCP, which is less than ideal because quite a few clients are legacy, scripted processes that use SCP rather than SFTP (the server we're replacing supported both protocols), and since those clients are not under our control and easily modified, it's likely not practical to disable SCP altogether.

It makes sense that this configuration would disable SCP, as incoming SCP connections cause sshd to spawn an `scp' process via the user's login shell, as that user. It seems that the same would normally be true of SFTP, were it not for the special 'internal-sftp' handler.

So, I suppose my question is: is there a way to achieve the same effect as 'internal-sftp' but for SCP, without resorting to the use of third-party tools like scponly and rssh?  The really nice thing about 'internal-sftp' is that it doesn't require setting up a jail with support files, or dealing with potentially-exploitable third party setuid binaries (rssh, in particular, has a history of exploits).

Comment: Are the clients connecting using an ssh key file, or are they using passwords? If it's a keyfile, it's possible to restrict what they can do.

Comment: They are connecting with passwords.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [rssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rssh) which is an alternative shell that allows limited access to a system.

> rssh  is  a restricted shell for providing limited access to a host via
>          ssh(1), allowing a user whose shell is configured to rssh to use one or
>          more  of the command(s) scp(1), sftp(1) cvs(1), rdist(1), and rsync(1),
>          and only those commands.

You can configure which commands can be used on a per-user or system wide basis using the [rssh.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rssh.conf) file

Alternatively you can use [scponly](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/scponly-full) to do what you want. It acts as a wrapper to the ssh suite and allows file transfer but not shell access.

Comment: `rssh` is no longer considered secure: "Sadly RSSH died a horrible death in 2019 when it became clear that providing restricted access to arbitrary programs is nearly impossible" ([see](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/)).

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to do this through ssh?

IF so you can try setting their shell to:

```
/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

And make sure you add the above into /etc/shells

If you want to decouple from using built in accounts, you can setup proftpd

I setup a secure SFTP using proftpd. compiled proftpd like so:

./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --with-modules=mod_sftp

Can use this article below, and some more on google on how to set it up:

http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.com/2012/02/linux-installing-and-configuring.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is nothing similarly easy or reliable with OpenSSH, since as you observed there is a built-in SFTP server, but no built-in SCP server.

A warning: the suggestion in the [answer by Vince Berk](https://serverfault.com/a/420490) is bad for a number of reasons:

1. The shell's behavior with regard to startup files can be influenced by environment variables, which SSH can remotely set depending on server configuration.
2. The user can just run `ssh /bin/bash` and get a shell. It won't have a tty and so will be inconvenient to use, but so what … . Not to mention all the other programs he can run that you presumably don't want him to.
3. Changing the permissions of `.bash_profile` does little good if the user can just do `ssh host rm -f .bash_profile`. Nothing was mentioned about the home directory permissions.

… and so on. This sort of approach is just way too fragile.

Answer (score 2):

Due to a weird coincidence, **you don't need to change anything** if the `scp` clients use **OpenSSH ≥8.8**. Means, you can then keep your current setup using `ForceCommand internal-sftp` to provide a SFTP server. It works because the scp *protocol* was deprecated in the `scp` command, in favour of the sftp protocol.

[Quoting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SCP_and_SFTP#Secure_copy_protocol_(SCP)) the Archlinux Wiki:

> **Note:** Since OpenSSH 8.8 the *scp* utility uses the SFTP protocol by default. The `-O` option must be used to use the legacy SCP protocol.
>
> **Warning:** The scp protocol is outdated, inflexible and not readily fixed. Its authors recommend the use of more modern protocols like sftp and rsync for file transfer instead [[see here](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2019-March/037672.html)].

For more background and a description of corner cases where you have to adapt your `scp` commands, see also the [announcement by RedHat](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/openssh-scp-deprecation-rhel-9-what-you-need-know).

Answer (score 0):

This is a third party tool, which is not in scope of the question, but I thought it deserves a mention anyway.

Jailkit: https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/

It has a collection of tools to make it easy to set up user jails - copying binaries and libraries to the jail, and setting up the logging from inside the jail to the OS. I've used it build sftp/scp/rsync-only chroots.

It also comes with `jk_lsh` (jailkit limited shell) which can be used outside the jail to limit the commands a user can run, if e.g. you want to allow scp/sftp/rsync only without chroot.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a trick on how to perform this serverside.  Set the shell of the users to, say, bash:

```
usermod -S /bin/bash [username]
```

Now create in their homedir a '.bash_profile' with the following line:

```
[ -n "$PS1" ] && exit
```

This causes non-interactive sessions (like 'scp') to continue.  However, if they attempt an 'ssh' login, the 'exit' is called, and the connection is closed.

Make sure they cannot 'sftp' a new '.bash_profile' into their home directories!

```
chown root:root .bash_profile
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This approach does not seem to take the requirement for the jail into account.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you would have to create a manual chroot environment for the 'scp' side, overlapping with the chroot directory given in sshd_config, and perform the above trick for each user you want to restrict.  The 'scp' does not work with the internal sftp server.